# Where are namespaces declared in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I learned in php that to be able to use a namespace, you have to declare or include first.

```
<?php
    namespace namespace_01;

    function f1()
    {
        echo 'this is function';
    }

    use namespace_01 as test_namespace;
    test_namespace\f1();
?>
```

Almost all of laravel codes use namespaces. But where are they defined?

Example,

when I created a controller.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class controller1 extends Controller
{
    //
}
```

where is `Illuminate\Http\Request` defined?

Comment: Set up proper IDE like PhpStorm and you will have experience boost via cmd+click on anything. Other IDE like editors (free) do the same with more configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open file from `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php`

There you will see the namespace declared on top as `namespace Illuminate\Http;` and the class name is `Request`

and you can see in your `composer.json` file

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
```

so all the classes inside App folder are auto loaded with composer and also the vendor files. you don't need to include files every time.

Comment: Thanks @Emtiaz. Ok all classes inside App folder are autoloaded.But where is the code autoloading vendor folder?

Comment: did you run composer install ?

Comment: if you already did then you should see the vendor folder in your project root directory

Comment: composer autoloads the App folder. Does composer also autoloads the vendor folder?

Comment: look at every package folder inside there are composer.json file included. that's how packages classes are also auto loaded

Answer (score 2):

These are found in the [Laravel Framework](https://github.com/laravel/framework/tree/5.7/src/Illuminate). Laravel uses [composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#introduction) to automatically load these packages. You can find the source in your `/vendor` folder, this is where composer puts the packages.

Comment: Thanks @jerodev. You said automatically load.You mean all these packages? Is this one reason why sometimes laravel is slow.? It loads all of these even you dont need it.

Comment: Most of the classes in Laravel Framework are deferred, meaning that they are only loaded when needed.

Comment: "DEFERRED". Thanks @Jerodev