# composer autoload in laravel

Tags: laravel, composer-php, autoload, psr-4

Looking at composer.json file in laravel project, 
I can find below

```
    "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ]
},
```

as far as I know App\:"app/" means a name space starts with App has its source files under the app/ directory and it follows psr-4.

however, there are ton's of packages under the vendor directory for instance packages start with Illuminate.. 
Are they under psr-4 or classmap? why are they not declared in the composer.json file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every package should be responsible for autoloading itself

Consider [Laravel](https://github.com/laravel/framework) as a single package like others

You can find vendor `composer.json` files in each packages separately

Here are the directory structure

```
<web-root>
    |--------src/
    |           |--------App/
    |           |
    |           |--------Test/
    |
    |---------library/
    |
    |---------vendor/
    |           |
    |           |---------composer/
    |           |           |---------autoload_psr4.php
    |           |           
    |           |----------autoload.php
    |
    |-----------composer.json
    |
```

You can take a look my another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52754867/where-are-namespaces-declared-in-laravel/52755288#52755288) for this autoload classmap